# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Tags: python-3.x, pydub

*Saludos. Corro este codigo en Python version 3.60*

```
import urllib.request
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# Download an audio file
urllib.request.urlretrieve("web", "metallic-drums.wav")
# Load into PyDub
#loop = AudioSegment.from_wav("Prueba_para_Python_1.m4a")
loop = AudioSegment.from_wav("metallic-drums.wav")
# Play the result
#play(loop)

# Repeat 2 times
loop2 = loop * 2
# Get length in milliseconds
length = len(loop2)
# Set fade time
fade_time = int(length * 0.5)
# Fade in and out
faded = loop2.fade_in(fade_time).fade_out(fade_time)

# Download another loop
urllib.request.urlretrieve("web", "beat.wav")
# Load into PyDub
beat = AudioSegment.from_wav("beat.wav")
# Mix with our original loop
mixed = beat[:length].overlay(loop2)

# Filter the beat at 3kHz
filtered = beat.low_pass_filter(3000)
# Mix loop2 with a reversed, panned version
loop = loop2.reverse().pan(-0.5).overlay(loop2.pan(0.5))
# Mix our filtered beat with the new loop at -3dB
final = filtered.overlay(loop2 - 3, loop=True)

final.export("final.mp3", format="mp3")
```

*Y obtengo este resultado en el Python Shell*

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\ScriptdeAudio1\ScriptdeAudio1.py 

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 165
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 179
    warn("Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\ScriptdeAudio1\ScriptdeAudio1.py", line 36, in <module>
    final.export("final.mp3", format="mp3")
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 868, in export
    p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdin=devnull, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>>>
```

*De las fallas anteriores, la que más me preocupa es la tercera porque está activada en la última línea del código y me impide obtener una variable final que contenga el archivo mp3 que debería, esta variable se crea pero sin contenido.

¿Qué puede ser? según veo, la llamada al comando **export** causa el problema, pero si todas las bibliotecas se cargan sin inconvenientes y Python es la versión 3.60, que es una versión ya revisada, ¿por qué ocurre este error?.*

Comment: Hola Angel, tanto los warnigs como la excepción tienen la misma causa, ¿tienes  [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) o libav instaladas y agregadas al PATH? pydub necesita una de ellas como dependencia si trabajas con archivos que no sean WAV, en tu caso solo usas WAV que está soportado gracias a la STDLib del propio Python, hasta la conversión a mp3, que efectivamente realiza el método `export`, de ahí la excepción final.